# Contraction mapping in the context of $f(x_n)=x_{n+1}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm interested in convergence of $f(x_n)=x_{n+1}$ and often hear this term referenced.

What does it mean to be a contraction mapping in the context of the sequence of real numbers given by $f(x_n)=x_{n+1}$? And what does it tell us about such sequence?

A search online gives the answer given by Wikipedia, that it is a function $f$ defined on a metric space $(M,d)$ from $M$ to itself with the property that for some real number $k \in [0,1)$,

$$d(f(x),f(y)) \leq k d(x,y)$$

This definition is quite unhelpful because I barely know what a metric space is. I feel like this definition is to generalized, and I'm interested in in the specific case of recursively defined real sequences $f(x_n)=x_{n+1}$ that there should be a more specific answer to my question.

Comment: Is it useful to mention that the "contractive" nomenclature is motivated by the fact that the points of the sequence get closer and closer together? (I'm possibly misunderstanding the purpose of the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contraction maps should be considered together with [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem). So ...

> What does it mean to be a contraction mapping in the context of the
>   sequence of real numbers given by $f(x_n)=x_{n+1}$?

As others stated $d(x,y)= |x-y|$ is a metric.

> And what does it tell us about such sequence?

Well, it tells that the sequence [is Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence). I.e.
$$|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|=|f(x_{n})-f(x_{n-1})|\leq k |x_{n}-x_{n-1}|\leq ... \leq k^{n}|x_1-x_0|$$
and with this in mind:
$$|x_{n+p}-x_n|=|x_{n+p}-x_{n+p-1}+x_{n+p-1}-x_n|=|x_{n+p}-x_{n+p-1}+...+x_{n+1}-x_n|\leq \\
|x_{n+p}-x_{n+p-1}|+...+|x_{n+1}-x_n|
\leq k^{n+p-1}|x_{1}-x_{0}|+..+k^{n}|x_{1}-x_{0}|=\\
|x_{1}-x_{0}|\left(k^{n+p-1} + ... +k^{n}\right)=k^{n}|x_{1}-x_{0}|\left(k^{p-1} + ... +1\right)<...$$
with the last term, we can add all the terms of the geometric progression because $0\leq k < 1$ and 
$$... < k^{n}|x_{1}-x_{0}|\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}k^t=\frac{k^n}{1-k}|x_{1}-x_{0}| \rightarrow 0, n\rightarrow \infty$$

But, we know that every [Cauchy sequence in a complete metric space has a limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space) and every compact is also complete. Also, every segment of the form $[\alpha, \beta] \subset  \mathbb{R}$ is compact.

Here comes Banach fixed-point theorem saying that if $f:[\alpha, \beta] \rightarrow [\alpha, \beta]$ is a contraction mapping then it admits a unique fixed point $f(x^*)=x^*$ and for $\forall x_0 \in [\alpha, \beta]$ the sequence constructed like $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ has $x^*$ as its limit. From this perspective

> Contraction mapping in the context of $f(x_n)=x_{n+1}$.

is a way to check if the sequence converges.

Answer (score 1):

The usual metric on the real numbers is
$$d(x,y) = |x-y|.$$

In other words, we have that
$$d(f(x),f(y))\leq k\cdot d(x,y)\quad\implies\quad |f(x)-f(y)|\leq k\cdot |x-y|.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ (that is, its input and output is a real number), then $f$ is a contraction mapping if there is a number $0 < k < 1$ for which 
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \leq k|x - y|
$$
for all $x,y$.