# Prove convergence of continuous fraction

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am studying real analysis and I have to show that the following recursively defined sequence $$x_{1}=\frac{1}{2} ; x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2+x_{n}}$$ converges to $L = \sqrt{2} - 1$. My intention was first to show that the sequence converges to later find the limit using $ L = \frac{1}{L+2} $, however I don't know how to prove that the sequence converges since I already know that it is not monotone so I can't use the Monotone Convergence Theorem. I would appreciate any hints so I can try to solve this problem, thanks.

Comment: Try to invert the sequence, i.e find the expression where  $x_n = ...$ and see if it gives you some intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x_{n+1}
=\frac{1}{2+x_{n}}
$.

Let
$c = \sqrt{2}-1$
and
$y_n = x_n-c
$.

Showing $x_n \to c$
is the same as
$y_n \to 0$.

We have
$y_{n+1}+c
=\frac{1}{2+y_{n}+c}
$
or,
since $c^2 = 3-2\sqrt{2}$,

$\begin{array}\\
y_{n+1}
&=\dfrac{1}{2+y_{n}+c}-c\\
&=\dfrac{1-c(2+y_{n}+c)}{2+y_{n}+c}\\
&=\dfrac{1-2c-c^2-2cy_{n}}{2+y_{n}+c}\\
&=\dfrac{1-2(\sqrt{2}-1)-(3-2\sqrt{2})-2cy_{n}}{2+y_{n}+c}\\
&=\dfrac{-2cy_{n}}{\sqrt{2}+1+y_{n}}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$0 < 2c < 1$,
if $|y_n| < 1$
then
$|y_{n+1}|
\lt \dfrac{|y_n|}{\sqrt{2}}
$
so $y_n \to 0$.

Since
$x_1 = \frac12$,
$y_1
=\frac12-(\sqrt{2}-1)
=\frac32-\sqrt{2}
\approx 1.5-1.414
=0.086
$
so
$|y_1| < \frac12
\lt 1$.

Therefore
$y_n \to 0$.

Rigorously,
$|\frac32-\sqrt{2}| < 1$
is the same as
$-1
\lt \frac32-\sqrt{2}
\lt 1
$
which is the same as
$(\sqrt{2}\lt \frac52)$
and
$(\sqrt{2} \gt \frac12)$
both of which follow from squaring.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the form of the potential limit let set $u_n=x_n+1$

$u_1=x_1+1=\frac 32$ and $u_{n+1}=x_{n+1}+1=\frac{1}{2+u_n-1}+1=\frac{2+u_n}{1+u_n}$

Now the trick is to use $m^2=2$ so that $m=\sqrt{2}$ is the limit of $u_n$. (we are not interested in the negative one, since $u_n\ge 0$ is easy to prove).

Notice that $u_{n+1}-m=\frac{m^2+u_n}{1+u_n}-m=-\frac{(m-1)(u_n-m)}{1+u_n}$

In particular $\dfrac{u_{n+1}-m}{u_n-m}<0$ this means that the values of $u_n$ are one side of the limit then the other side (you have a spiral convergence).

So now prove $u_{2n}$ and $u_{2n+1}$ are monotone adjacent sequences (one $\searrow$, the other $\nearrow$) bounded (lower or upper) by $m$ and thus convergent to $m$.

Hint: study the sign of $f(f(u))-u=(m^2-u^2)\times(\text{positive stuff})$ still with $f(u)=\frac{m^2+u}{1+u}$

See [a similar problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/3538354/399263)