# Prove if $\vert a_{n+1}-a_n\vert\leq \ q\vert a_n - a_{n-1} \vert$ then $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, cauchy-sequences

I’m tasked with proving the following:

> For $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $q\in \mathbb{R}$ with $0<q<1$ and $n \geq n_0$, let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. If
>   $$\vert a_{n+1}-a_n\vert\leq q\vert a_n - a_{n-1} \vert$$ then $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

I thought it may be possible by trying to "form" it in such a way that I can use the ratio test, but it doesn't really work it seems. Alternatively I thought it's sufficient to prove that the sequence converges since that would automatically mean that it's a Cauchy sequence, but it seems to me that there is to little to work with. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Write $\left | a_{n+1}-a_{n} \right | \le{q^n} \left | a_{n_{o}+1}-a_{n_o} \right | $

Comment: @DigAmma I don't think I quite understand. Could you please elaborate on that thought a little bit?

Comment: Sending it in form of solution

Comment: Have a look at [this question/answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2225451/contraction-mapping-in-the-context-of-fx-n-x-n1/2225503#2225503) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

As $\forall n>n_o $
$$\left | a_{n+1} -a_n\right | \le q \left |  a_{n} -a_{n-1}\right | $$
Let$ n =n_o+1$
$$\left | a_{n_{o}+2} -a_{n_o+1}\right | \le q \left |  a_{n_{o}+1} -a_{n_{o}}\right | $$
$n=n_o+2$
$$\left | a_{n_o+3} -a_{n_{o+2}}\right | \le q \left |  a_{n_o+2} -a_{n_o+1}\right |  \le q^2 \left | a_{n_o+1} -a_{n_{o}}\right | $$
Now generalizing give

$$\left | a_{n+1} -a_{n}\right | \le q^{n-n_o} \left |  a_{n_o+1} -a_{n_o}\right | $$
Now let $ \lim_{n \to \infty}$
To get $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left | a_n-a_{n-1} \right | =0$

Comment: I hope you understand

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Two things still remain a bit unclear to me. If we state that $\forall n>n_o$ how are we allowed to say $n =n_o$. Secondly the step from the second to third inequality in the third line is unclear to me. Since 0<q<1 wouldn't $q^2$ make it so that it is less than the inequality with q infront of it?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it and we get from 2nd to third by multiplying the first inequality by q

Comment: Alright thanks for clarifying. Just to be sure: the last line is the defining criteria to show that it is a Cauchy sequnence, correct?

Comment: Unfortunately $|a_{n} - a_{n-1}| \to 0$ does not imply that $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Instead, you should look at the answer mentioned by @rtybase which points to the correct answer.